# Concatenating returned elements to list in a recursive function

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

This one has been giving me a headache for too long

I am trying to create a list of tuples from a recursion, but I can't quite figure out if how I'm approaching this is going to work or not.
Below, foo() and A are aliases for more complicated methods and structures, but I'd like foo() below to return the following:

> [(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4), (5, 5), (6, 6), (7, 7), (8,
>   8)]

## First attempt

When I try adding them together as lists, it nests all the lists.

```
A = [(num, num) for num in np.arange(9)]
def foo(A):

    if len(A)==1:
        return(A[0])
    else:
        return([A[0]] + [foo(A[1:])])
print(foo(A))
```

> output: [(0, 0), [(1, 1), [(2, 2), [(3, 3), [(4, 4), [(5, 5), [(6, 6),
>   [(7, 7), (8, 8)]]]]]]]]

## Second attempt

I can understand why this is wrong, so I tried appending the returned values to the list at the higher level, nothing returns:

```
A = [(num, num) for num in np.arange(9)]
def foo(A):

    if len(A)==1:
        return(A[0])
    else:
        return([A[0]].append(foo(A[1:])))
print(foo(A))
```

> output: None

## Current solution (there's got to be a better way)

```
def foo(A):

    if len(A)==1:
        return(A[0])
    else:
        return(A[0] + foo(A[1:]))
```

> output: (0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8)

...then:

```
temp = np.array(foo(A)).reshape(-1,2)
output = [tuple(temp[i, :]) for i in range(np.shape(temp)[0])]
print(output)
```

which gives the desired output...
Can someone give some advice on how to do this correctly using recursion?

Comment: You realize that "A" already contains what you say you are expecting as return, don't you?

Comment: Yes. it's an abstraction for a more complex example. In other words solving this simple case gives me the information I need to solve a more complex example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pretty much had it on your first try. By adding an unpacking and altering your original base case, we can get your desired result.

```
def foo(A):

    if len(A)==1:
        return([A[0]])
    else:
        return([A[0]] + [*foo(A[1:])])
print(foo(A))
```

Comment: Why `[*foo(A[1:])]` instead of just `foo(A[1:])`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are asking for since A is already the structure you want. But for your first attempt, you mess up the return type. The first `if` returns a number, but the second `if` returns a list. So make sure the first `if` returns a list, and remove the list conversion in the second `if`. It should be like this:

```
import numpy as np

A = [(num, num) for num in np.arange(9)]
def foo(A):

    if len(A)==1:
        return([A[0]])
    else:
        return([A[0]] + foo(A[1:]))
print(foo(A))
```